# ConTeXt: Dynamically setting frame width around section using \structureuservariable

Tags: context, framed

I would like to generate graphical sections (for poster/slides) where the section is bounded by a frame and the section title itself also has a graphic around it. However, I would like to generate these graphics/frames with variable widths, defined when the section is placed. It seems like `\structureuservariable` should be perfect for this task (and I can use it to set colours), but this approach doesn't work for widths:

```
\defineframedtext[Highlight]

\setuphead[section]
[textcolor=\structureuservariable{color}, 
before={\startHighlight[width=local,framecolor=\structureuservariable{color}]},
after={\stopHighlight},
beforesection={\startHighlight[width=\structureuservariable{width}]},
aftersection={\stopHighlight}]

\starttext

\startsection[title={Test}][width=2in, color=red]

% Double checking that \structureuservariable works with width
\startHighlight[width=\structureuservariable{width}]
test
\stopHighlight

\stopsection
\stoptext
```

As shown in the example above, defining a frame within the section works fine with the correct width, but not using `beforesection`/`aftersection` keys.

Is there a way to make this work whether using `\structureuservariable` or not?

Comment: You can't pass userdata to the `beforesection` key because it is inserted before ConTeXt reads the arguments for the section command.

Comment: In addition to what Wolfgang said, there is also a comment about this in [`strc-sec.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/5f6a7c6790baa7e524de5b5bf71a29ea757378f6/tex/context/base/mkiv/strc-sec.mkiv#L669): `\headparameter\c!beforesection % beware, no users vars set yet` You could use `insidesection` instead of `beforesection` but that won't include the section title.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster, @HenriMenke OK thanks, that makes sense. It's pretty easy to set the width with explicit calls to `\setupframedtext[Highlight][width=2in]` but I thought that `\structureuservariable` would have been the more elegant method.